# In a relation, how can I get the data of table A but not have in table B?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have:

Questions table:

| id | question name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1+1 ? |
| 2 | 2+2 = ? |

Options table

| id | option name | question_id | is_correct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 33 | 1 | 0 |

Model question:

```
class question extends Model{
use HasFactory;
public function options()
{
    return $this->hasMany(option::class, 'question_id', 'id');
}
}
```

1. How to get the questions in the "questions" table but in the "options" table there are no options?
2. How to get the questions in the "question" table but in the "options" table there is no correct option?

Thanks

Comment: so you want to fetch data from questions table for the given two above condition, condition 1) when there are no options currently for the question 2) when there are no correct options for the given table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if I understand your question correctly but

In your controller

```
$options = Options::with('question')->get();
```

In blade:

```
@foreach ($options as $option);

    {{$option->question->name}}

@endforeach
```

Kr